Converting pdf to avif with Imagick results in images that dont display in Safari
I use Imagick to convert pdf-files to avif files. It is done in a container and I install imagemagick, imagemagick-pdf and imagemagick-heic.
My initial approach was magick -density 600 ./$f -resize 400x ./output/${f%.*}.avi but this resulted in blank images when viewied in Safari.
After a bit of trial an error I managed to get a result with magick -density 600 ./$f -resize 400x -alpha off ./output/${f%.*}.avi, but then some images got a black background. I tried setting the background to white magick -density 600 ./$f -resize 400x -background white -alpha background ./output/${f%.*}.avi, but then we were back to blank images.
The solution was to use -alpha remove:
magick -density 600 ./$f -resize 400x -alpha remove ./output/${f%.*}.avi.
So I have something that works, but it is a result of trial and error.
I would like to understand if this is a bug with avif in Safari. I would also like to know if there is a more robust way of doing this.
